# How to convert an SQL result string to an array in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, codeigniter

I need transform the **[pictures names]** string  to an array. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: refrain from using code images, put the code base as `<code>` in the question, `explode()`

Comment: use explode() function

Comment: You don't need to insert tags into your questions titles, there is already a tag cloud below your question. And this is what the answering people uses. It is much more useful if you give your question a very clear, descriptive, well-formatted title.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your $array[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)[picture_names] into an array itself, you can use the "[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)" function.

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
```

I.e in your specific example:

```
$results = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$exp_results = explode(',', $results);
```

Which should give an array as such:

```
$exp_results = Array (
    0 => 21
    1 => 22
    2 => 25
    3 => 27
    4 => .... etc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines after query

```
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
foreach($result as $key=>$row) {
    $result[$key]['picture_names'] = explode(',',$row['picture_names']);
}
```